# Adding controller methods in ex_admin (Phoenix)

Tags: elixir, admin, backend, phoenix-framework

I am working with the [ex_admin](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin) package for Phoenix.  After doing a successful standard install, I create a `User` resource with a name and an avatar (which will reference a file on S3)

`>> mix phoenix.gen.model User users name:string avatar:string`

`>> mix admin.gen.resource User`

```
modules: [
    MyApp.ExAdmin.Dashboard,
    MyApp.ExAdmin.User
]
```

`>> iex -S mix phoenix.server`

Works great.  Now I'd like to add modify the equivalent of the `create` function that would exist in `web/controllers/user_controller.ex` if I had made the resource with `mix phoenix.gen.html User ...`.  However, despite the fact that the backend is CRUD'ing properly, I can't find any controllers for this specific resource.

What is the best way to tackle this?  Create a `web/controllers/user_controller.ex` file and have it override?  Add the function as a module elsewhere?

Comment: Steve here, creator of ex_admin. Can you be a little more specific about what you want to do in the create action? There are a couple ways to modify controllers which I'll explain once I understand what your trying to do.

Comment: @StevePallen Hi Steve.  This question is a little general, because I was looking for a general practice for this type of situation (if there is one).  As an example, let's say it it uploads the avatar to S3 when the new user is created, and then sends me an email alert.

Comment: For something that simple, you can probably use option 1 I described below. You don't even need anything in the controller if you use something like [arc_ecto](https://hex.pm/packages/arc_ecto). Then you could add an `after_filter` to send the email. If you want to see file uploads, take a look at [ExAdmin Demo](http://demo.exadmin.info/admin/products) and the [source](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin_demo).

Comment: @StevePallen  Does ex_admin work with Phoenix 1.3, or is there a migration path?  I just upgraded and I'm getting `deps/ex_admin/mix.exs requires ~> 1.2 *`.

Comment: I have not tested it on a project created with `phx.new`. But I suspect there will be some issues. BTW, you can get around dependency issues like this by adding `override: true` option to the main dependency in your `mix.exs` file. `{:my_dep, "~> 1.3", override: true}`

Comment: This [PR](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin/pull/322) would suggest that someone has tried it. You can also look at [this issue](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin/issues/335) for more information. I'll do my best to test it in the next couple of days.

Comment: I just pushed a phx-1.3 branch with experiment support for the new project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two ways you can hook into controller actions in ExAdmin.

**1. Add either a `before_filter` or an `after_filter` on the controller.**

For this approach, use the `controller` macro in your resource file.

```
defmodule MyApp.ExAdmin.License do
  use ExAdmin.Register
  register_resource MyApp.License do
    # ...
    controller do
      before_filter :set_current_user, only: [:create, :update]
      before_filter :set_updated_by, only: [:update]

      def set_current_user(conn, params) do
        new_params = put_in(params, [:license, :user_id], MyApp.Authentication.current_user(conn).id)
        {conn, new_params}
      end
      def set_updated_by({conn, params}, _params) do
        new_params = put_in(params, [:license, :updated_by_id], MyApp.Authentication.current_user(conn).id)
        {conn, new_params}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Checkout the docs from master [here](https://github.com/smpallen99/ex_admin/blob/master/lib/ex_admin/register.ex#L395)

**2. Create you own controller**

With this approach, you create a controller with the actions you want to override. To use your custom controller, you will need to add routes for the desired actions. Just make sure the routes you create are above this block in your router.

```
scope "/admin", ExAdmin do
  pipe_through :browser
  admin_routes
end
```

Here is an example of a custom controller. Note that you need to include the `@resource "my_resource"`.

```
defmodule ExAdmin.ClientController do
  @resource "clients"
  use ExAdmin.Web, :resource_controller
  alias UcxRemote.{Client, Repo, ClientService}
  require Logger
  use Utils

  def create(conn, _defn, %{_format: "json", client: client_params} = _params) do
    result = do_create conn, client_params
    case result do
      {:ok, client} ->
        put_view(conn, UcxRemote.ApiClientView)
        |> render("create.json", client: client)
      {:error, _changeset} ->
        json conn, %{errors: ["Validation failed"]}
    end
  end

  def create(conn, defn, params) do
    result = do_create conn, params[:client]
    case result do
      {:ok, client} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:notice, "Client was successfully created.")
        |> redirect(to: admin_resource_path(client, :show))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        errors = get_errors(changeset, "creating")
        conn
        |> put_flash(:error, errors)
        |> handle_changeset_error(defn, changeset, params)
    end
  end

  defp do_create(conn, %{user_id: user_id} = client_params) do
    changeset = %Client{user_id: user_id}
    |> Repo.preload([user: :company])
    |> Client.changeset(client_params)
    Repo.insert(changeset)
  end
end
```

Here is the route:

```
 scope "/", ExAdmin do
    pipe_through :browser
    post "/clients", ClientController, :create
 end
```